# IOS 11 Drag&Drop - Import/Load .cbz files

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, ios11

How can you load `.cbz` that are being dropped into the app using `Drag&Drop` in iOS 11?

I tried something like this because I thought `.cbz` is just data:

```
// Inside collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator)
item.itemProvider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeData as String) { (data, error) in
    print(data) // data is nil
}
```

However, it's not working. Is there a way to import these "exotic" file types?

Comment: CBZ is not exotic, it's just a ZIP file with a different extension...

Comment: I know, but I can't really rename it before importing it.I tried `kUTTypeZipArchive` and it didn't work. With exotic, I meant "not in `UTCoreTypes`"

Comment: So what you actually want is to add "cbz" to available types, right?

Comment: Yes. Once I can load the file, I know how to handle it. But I don't know how to import it in the first place

Comment: I tested a few different `.cbz` files from different sources and printed their `registeredTypeIdentifier`. It's always `dyn.ah62d46dzqm0gw23srf4gn5m4ge80g2x4`. But is it guaranteed to be the same for all `.cbz` files?

Comment: Okay, using the `mdls` command in terminal, I get `dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80g2x4` as content type of a `.cbz file`. That's similar, but not identical to the one above. Strangely, this `dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80g2x4 ` identifier doesn't work.